# Adding ListView with EditTexts in each child - Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am creating an app which will allow users to input data into each child cell. Also when the user clicks the bottom-most cell it adds an extra child to the parent. However, when I add a new child, all the inputted data in the old child cells disappear.

Also is there an optimal way to save all the data inputted into each cell?

The class that controls view:

```
public class CustomWorkout extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListView expandableListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_workout);

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expWorkout);
    final List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>();
    final HashMap<String, List<String>> child = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    Spinner spinnerSplit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSplit);

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CustomWorkout.this, R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.split));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSplit.setAdapter(myAdapter);

   final ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, headings, child);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    spinnerSplit.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            headings.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < position + 1; i++) {
                    String add = "Day " + Integer.toString(i + 1);
                   List<String> put = new ArrayList<String>();
                   put.add("Add a Workout");
                    headings.add(add);
                    child.put(add, put);
                }
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    if (childPosition == listViewAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition) - 1) {
                        String header = "Day " + (groupPosition + 1);
                        child.get(header).add("Add a Workout");
                        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}
```

}

Class for adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private List<String> headerTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> childItems;
private Context context;

ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> headerTitle, HashMap<String, List<String>> childItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
    this.childItems = childItems;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return headerTitle.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return childItems.get(headerTitle.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return headerTitle.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childItems.get(headerTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String) this.getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_header, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerParent);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setText(title);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int count = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);

    String title = (String) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView == null) {
        if (!isLastChild) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_workout, null);
        } else if (isLastChild) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerChild);
            textView.setText(title);
        }
    } else {
        if (isLastChild) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerChild);
            textView.setText(title);
        } else {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_workout, null);

        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Pardon, where is the `EditText `on your `getChildView`? Can I assume that you're not just using `findViewById` on it because you're not going to use anything of it? I know a solution for this, I just want to clarify if the `EditText` is there

Comment: Its in a xml file (add_workout) that the getChildView calls. Not to sure how to determine which EditText belongs to which cell either yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `adapter`, add an `interface` and modify its `constructor` to this:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

   private List<String> headerTitle;
   private HashMap<String, List<String>> childItems;
   private Context context;
   HasMap<String, String> editTextValues;
   private OnEditTextChangeListener onEditTextChangeListener;

   public interface OnEditTextChangeListener {
      void onEditChange(String key, String value);
   }

   ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> headerTitle, HashMap<String, List<String>> childItems, HasMap<String, String> editTextValues, OnEditTextChangeListener onEditTextChangeListener) {
       this.context = context;
       this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
       this.childItems = childItems;
   }

   ....code code codes....

   @Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int count = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);

    String title = (String) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView == null) {
        if (!isLastChild) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_workout, null);
            EditText editText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idOfYourEditText);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : editTextValues.entrySet()) { //loop to set the values that you saved
              Log.d("KING_DEBUG", "Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value:" + entry.getValue()); //add this so we can log it if we are actually saving the edittext values
              if (entry.getKey().equals(title)) {
                 editText.setText(entry.getValue());
              }
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  onEditTextChangeListener.onEditChange(title, editable.toString());
               }
           });


        } else if (isLastChild) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerChild);
            textView.setText(title);
        }
    } else {
        if (isLastChild) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerChild);
            textView.setText(title);
        } else {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_workout, null);
            EditText editText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.idOfYourEditText);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : editTextValues.entrySet()) { //loop to set the values that you saved
              Log.d("KING_DEBUG", "Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value:" + entry.getValue()); //add this so we can log it if we are actually saving the edittext values
              if (entry.getKey().equals(title)) {
                 editText.setText(entry.getValue());
              }
            }
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                  onEditTextChangeListener.onEditChange(title, editable.toString());
               }
           });
        }
    }

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

On your `activity`:

```
public class CustomWorkout extends AppCompatActivity {

   ExpandableListView expandableListView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_workout);

    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expWorkout);
    final List<String> headings = new ArrayList<String>();
    final HashMap<String, List<String>> child = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    final HashMap<String, String> editTextValues = new HashMap<String, String>(); //add this

    Spinner spinnerSplit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSplit);

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CustomWorkout.this, R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.split));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSplit.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    final ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, headings, child, editTextValues, 
       new OnEditTextChangeListener () {
          @Override
          public void onEditChange(String key, String value) {
             editTextValues.put(key, value);
          }
       }); //modified constructor
    expandableListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    spinnerSplit.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            headings.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < position + 1; i++) {
                    String add = "Day " + Integer.toString(i + 1);
                   List<String> put = new ArrayList<String>();
                   put.add("Add a Workout");
                    headings.add(add);
                    child.put(add, put);
                }
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    if (childPosition == listViewAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition) - 1) {
                        String header = "Day " + (groupPosition + 1);
                        child.get(header).add("Add a Workout");
                        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Here, we've added `editTextValues` which saves the value of each `editText` upon changing, and the `custom listener` to handle it on the `activity`.

The trick is to save what you've input and set it every time you display it.

Comment: I get the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'OnEditTextChangeListener'

Comment: It seems you didn't add the `public interface OnEditTextChangeListener` above the constructor of adapter.

Comment: Error:(39, 21) error: cannot find symbol class OnEditTextChangeListener

Comment: Did you import it? It will be imported from your adapter. Press alt+Enter if you're on android studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162310/discussion-between-tenten-ponce-and-king).